# Variable offset number in exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

I trying to write a program that will open another exe file, jump to specified offset and change the content of the variable. I've already done it with program written in c++ (using HxD to find variable offset) but can't find any variable in same program written in python (ver. 3.7, exe created using pyinstaller). I think it's somehow compressed but I don't have any idea how to find those variables

Comment: What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478524/python-write-to-file-based-on-offset

Comment: Actually I am trying to find value in exe file which is hidden somehow, it's not like in txt file

Comment: Txt or Exe, you can open them in binary mode and scan over the bytes, as shown by a few methods in that post.